# OSS Flex Plugin for Eclipse ? [Experience Survey]

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, editor, eclipse-plugin

Could you please post your experience with any existing open source flex plugins for eclipse ? (anything other than flex builder).

Thanks,
-A

Answer (score 0):

There are not too many open source flex plugins for eclipse..check this [link](http://www.riaspace.net/2009/01/flex-developer-tools-ides/) for a brief description. Outside FB I like Intellij, but only the commercial version has the Flex plugin.